# How do I know if a Lat,Lng point has street view?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

this is my javascript code

```
Description += "<br><span class='descr'>Coordinate:</span> <span class='cont'><a href=\"" + mapsLink + "\" onclick=\"window.open('" + mapsLink + "')\">" + picRecords[index].getCoords() + "</span></a>";
```

and

```
var mapsLink = "https://maps.google.it/maps?q=" + picRecords[index].getLatitude() + "," + picRecords[index].getLongitude();
```

I would like that if a point (getLatitude,getLongitude) has street view open, another link on onClick.

Must I use some Google Maps API for this? which ?

thanks for the reply!

Comment: please explain this line better I cannot get what you want "I would like that if a point (getLatitude,getLongitude) has street view open, another link on onClick."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you would have to use the Google Maps API for this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService

The getPanoramaByLocation() function will tell you if there is a nearby panorama.

Answer (score 1):

What barryhunter says.  Here's how I do it.  I have an empty div that's already visible for the streetmap to go into.  Then I hide the div if the streetmap isn't available:

```
function createStreetMap(strMapCanvasID, intLat, intLong) {
    var streetViewLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(intLat, intLong);
    var panorama;
    var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    sv.getPanoramaByLocation(streetViewLocation, 50, function (data, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            var panoramaOptions = {
                pano: data.location.pano,
                addressControl: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById(strMapCanvasID), panoramaOptions);
        } else {
            $('#' + strMapCanvasID).parent().hide();
        }
    });
    return panorama;
}
```

Then I do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myPano = createStreetMap('streetView', 41.3884810185, 2.13370800018);
});
```